# Can Spring Hibernate lookup records with a foreign key?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Is it possible to get data using a foreign key?

When I want to lookup a user by primary key I use this:

```
public class UsersDaoImpl extends AbstractDao<Integer, Users> implements UsersDao {

    public Users findById(int id) {
        return getByKey(id);
       }
    }

    public abstract class AbstractDao<PK extends Serializable, T> {

    private final Class<T> persistentClass;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public AbstractDao() {
        this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[1];
    }

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T getByKey(PK key) {
        return (T) getSession().get(persistentClass, key);
    }
}
```

This works well, but I'm wondering how to do it using a foreign key.